# SQL Server Management Studio intellisense ceases to work until its help banner disappears

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, windows-10

When I open `SQL Server 2012 Management Studio` and start typing a query the `intellisense` does not work for some time until I wait for the following info banner to appear on the lower right corner of Windows 7 (or later).

**Question**: How can we disable the display of the following banner so it does not interfere in the appearance of `intellisense` - or are there any workarounds to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening this and choosing NO I am not interested or whatever?

Comment: This happens to me sometimes - it's a bug within SSMS.  Sometimes when I have it open, the intellisense will stop working.  I close it, reopen it, all is well.

Comment: ctrl-shift-r : you can try it when its not working

Comment: @StanShaw What you suggest works - it even works fine after the info banner appears. The issue is that info banner takes some time to appear and until then the `intellisense` does not work (that makes one think may be `intellisense` is not working). Moreover, you either wait for the info banner to appear or start hard coding the db object names (sometime you have to guess the object name while hard coding) in the query while info banner appear.

Comment: Again....open the banner and choose the option that you are not interested. It will no longer display. Then I would suggest finding a plugin intellisense as the native one is pretty bad.

Comment: @SeanLange Your suggestion worked. Although the radio button for option `I'm not interested` was by default checked in, I did have to open the banner and click on OK to get it working. Now the `intellisense` works right away even though the banner still appears after some time.

Comment: @SeanLange For benefit of other readers, you may want to change your comment - with brief detail if you like - to a `Response` and I'll mark it as an answer.